# How to find a ASCII value of text file in python?

Tags: python, encryption, jupyter-notebook, ascii

I want to input a text file in python and I want python to read that file and find the ASCII value of each character along with spaces and all numeric values.  What I have tried so far is this.

```
d={}
f = open("MyFile.txt","r")
input_message= f.read()
for i in range(len(input_message)):
    d[i]=0
    for it in input_message[i]:
        d[i]=ord(it)
public key = (3163, 103603)
def encrypt(d,public_key):
    key,n = public_key
    ctext = [pow(char,key,n) for char in d]
    return ctext
end_encrypt = time.time_ns()
```

This gives an error.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b7d0a6bd3c5e> in <module>
    104     #input_message = input("Enter the message = ")
    105 
--> 106     ctext = encrypt(input_message,public_key)
    107     print("encrypted:",ctext)
    108     plaintext = decrypt(ctext, private_key)

<ipython-input-4-b7d0a6bd3c5e> in encrypt(d, public_key)
     82 def encrypt(d,public_key):
     83     key,n = public_key
---> 84     ctext = [pow(char,key,n) for char in d]
     85     return ctext
     86 end_encrypt = time.time_ns()

<ipython-input-4-b7d0a6bd3c5e> in <listcomp>(.0)
     82 def encrypt(d,public_key):
     83     key,n = public_key
---> 84     ctext = [pow(char,key,n) for char in d]
     85     return ctext
     86 end_encrypt = time.time_ns()

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for pow(): 'str', 'int', 'int'
```

Currently I am using jupyter notebook. I am not sure where I am wrong.

Comment: Did you read the docs for [pow()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)? The arguments must have numeric types. The error message is telling you that you have passed in arguments of type str, int, int.

Comment: `f.read()` returns a single string. There's no need for the second loop, as `input_message[i]` is a single string of length 1. Or you might have intended to use `input_message = f.readlines()`.

Comment: @jarmod where to find it ? i am a beginner

Comment: @chepner it still gives the same error :(

Comment: Added a link to the pow() docs. You should not be passing characters such as 'A' to pow(); instead pass Ord('A') (which you seem to be trying to pre-calculate in `d`). It may simply be that you should have passed `d` to the encrypt function instead of passing `input_message`. BTW it doesn't help that you have not included all of the relevant code e.g. the actual call to `encrypt()`.

Answer (score 0):

Read it as a binary file.  Then you get a string of bytes, and no conversions are required:

```
def encrypt(d,public_key):
    key,n = public_key
    ctext = [pow(char,key,n) for char in d]
    return ctext

d = open("x.py","rb").read()
public_key = (3163, 103603)
print(encrypt( d, public_key ))
```

Comment: Thank you it worked . Is it possible to get the encrypted text to get in text file, this would help me a lot.

Comment: Come on, you have to do some of the work yourself.  One of the things you'll have to decide is how to encode it.  `ctext` is a list of integers less than 103603.  You can't just "write it to a text file".  You have to decide what it will look like.

Comment: Maybe `out = array.array('I', cipher)` / `out.tofile(open('encoded.bin','wb'))`

Comment: it gives the following error: 
`NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)`
`<ipython-input-13-295243209d7e> in <module>` 
`--> 113     out = array.array('I', cipher)`
 `   114     out.tofile(open('encoded.bin','wb'))`
    

`NameError: name 'array' is not defined`

Comment: And you can't figure that out?  Do you ever use Google?  Even as a beginner, you ought to be able to find standard modules.